# Salesforce Roles

Tags: salesforce, roles, profile

I have roles hierarchy in place. 
the new requirement is to set up permission to specific external users so they will not be able to see other users records.

the sharing setting for the object is set to Private. I cannot create a user without a role. Other users should be able to see other users (in their role) records. but only this few users should be able to see only records they own.

any idea how to solve it?

thanks,
Chen

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The community is willing to help solve programmatic issues, but not do the work for you. Please can you show us some code/things that you have already tried first.